# When I try connection and call Procedure to OracleDb with NodeJs Error: DPI-1010: not connected

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle

```
async dbCEI(inOut){

    try{
       var connection = await oracledb.getConnection(dbConfig);
       // console.log("Connection Success");
        //console.log(this.typeName2);
       var tp1 =await connection.getDbObjectClass(this.typeName1);
       var tp2 =await connection.getDbObjectClass(this.typeName2);
       // console.log(tp1);
        var getbinds = infoEmirIslem(inOut,tp1,tp2);
        await connection.execute(this.nlsLang);
        await connection.execute(this.nlsDateFormat);
        var result = await connection.execute(this.procedureCall,getbinds)  
        var firstinOut =result.outBinds.p_cq;
        var emir = result.outBinds.p_ARRAYOUT;
        var islem = result.outBinds.p_islemler;
        var emirArray = convertArray(emir);
      //  console.log(emirArray)
        var islemArray =convertArray(islem);
      //  console.log(islemArray)
                  //  console.log(saat)
                  return [firstinOut,emirArray,islemArray];
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

Inout parameter is 0 at the beginning. I will reconnect with the out parameter that comes after every second, and if there is new record on the first procedure I took, I will add them.
When I write connection.close() at the end of the function, it throws dp-1010 error directly.When I do not write connection.close (), the values ​​are updated every 4 and 5 times in seconds, but then it throws the same error. 
why does the connection disappear, what should I do

Comment: Can you show us `convertArray`? Is it sync or async?

Comment: Could you please update the code to include the `close` call? It's the only way we can see if you added it correctly. Also, what makes you think the error is coming from that part of your code? Can you show us the error message?

Comment: I will try async convertArray.
If I give an example, the code is working correctly for 5 seconds and I can get the results I want, but then the values ​​in the array are deleted and an error message appears for each column.

Comment: this is causing a problem with the connection

Comment: for example when result success  =  stock_code: Garan after gives error  = stock_code : DP-1010: not connected

Comment: module.exports.convertToArray=  function(result){
    resultArray =[];
    for(let i=0;i<result.length;i++){
    resultArray[i]= result[i]
    }
    return  resultArray;

}

Comment: I doubt this is causing your issue, but in `convertToArray`, you should have the `var` keyword before `resultArray =[];`, otherwise it could become a global variable.

Comment: thank you very much for your replies. I got the connection into the global. and it happened. respect to you.

Comment: Are you saying things are working now? If so, awesome! :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the `try` block has completed (and the connection closed) before the `convertArray` calls have finished.  This would be timing dependent. With Oracle objects, the connection needs to remain open until you have finished with the objects.

I noticed your two `execute()` calls to set the NLS environment.  This is two round trips between Node.js and the DB, so it is slow.  You may be able to do the same in a single call with a command like  `alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD' nls_language = AMERICAN`.  And/or set the values in NLS environment variables.

Depending on your app, can you use a pool and keep the connection open?  You would use a pool [`sessionCallback`](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/SessionCallback.py) to set the NLS values, if you don't set them via environment variables.

Comment: Thank you. If I could not  I will try Poll.